# Which W*-algebras are the duals of C*-coalgebras?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, coalgebras

A Banach algebra (assumed associative and unital) is precisely a monoid object in the monoidal category of Banach spaces, short linear maps, and the projective tensor product.  A Banach coalgebra is then a comonoid object in this monoidal category.  It's straightforward to write down what a Banach *-coalgebra is too.  It's a little less obvious what a C*-coalgebra is, and I don't know if that term appears in the literature, but [I've written down my definition](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/C-star-coalgebra).

Generally, the dual space of a coalgebra is an algebra (but not conversely), and that works here too: the dual of a C*-coalgebra is a C*-algebra.  But not every C*-algebra arises in this way; obviously, since all of these C*-algebras have preduals (having been explicitly constructed so), they are W*-algebras.  But I don't know what other conditions must be satisfied.

So my question is, and I'll be grateful for incomplete answers:  Which W*-algebras arise (up to abstract isomorphism) as duals of C*-coalgebras?

Partial answers:  The sequence space $l^\infty$ is the dual of $l^1$, and $l^1$ is a C*-coalgebra.  But this doesn't work for $L^\infty(R)$; this is the dual of $L^1(R)$, but I can't make $L^1(R)$ into even a Banach coalgebra (in an appropriate way), essentially because the diagonal in $R^2$ has measure zero.  (Unless I've miscalculated something, and I'm trying to do the wrong thing here.)  Of course, these are quite limited examples: they're (co)commutative.  I'd be grateful for more.

Comment: Warning bells sound in my head when I read your definition of a Banach coalgebra - I think the dead hand of dogma / the wisdom of experience says that one should be using a different tensor product for comonoids. (The problem is that $A\otimes A$ is too small if you take $\otimes$ as the canonical monoidal tensor for that category. Going to Cstar world won't help.)

Comment: Ah, on rereading, I think you might be OK in the (co)commutative setting, but that only works when your co-algebras are $\ell^1$. (This is all related to ideas people have been trying out for Hopf von Neumann algebras, but you are asking for less algebraic structure so I guess there may be more room to get some extra examples)

Comment: BTW, maybe this should be a co-$C^\ast$-algebra rather than a $C^\ast$-coalgebra, but it depends how you feel about clashes with terminology used by people in operator algebras.

Comment: With regard to Yemon's comment about projective tensor products, read Matt Daws' answer to this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/50302/can-we-recover-a-von-neumann-algebra-from-its-predual

Comment: With regard to Ollie's commemt, just ask Matt Daws about all this, quite frankly.

Comment: As already indicated by Ollie above, if we use the extended
Haagerup tensor product, then all von Neumann algebras
are duals of C*-coalgebras (well, I don't have a proof of
the co-C*-identity for preduals of von Neumann algebras,
but it seems plausible).  I would also like to add
that there is a lot of evidence that suggests that
in the framework of C*-algebras and von Neumann algebras
the “right” tensor product is often not the usual injective
or projective tensor product, but rather
one of the tensor products coming from the theory
of operator spaces, such as the one cited above.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what the extended Haagerup product actually means for plain Banach spaces, that is those without an action of an operator algebra or otherwise with the structure of operator spaces.

Comment: (In fact, it was after reading Matt Daws's answer to your question cited by Ollie above, and having this problem, that I decided to see what one could do with Banach coalgebras (not expecting to get all $W^*$-algebras this way but hopefully some), and the literature that I found on those used the projective tensor product.  But that literature was also mostly concerned with nonArchimedean spaces, so it just may not be relevant.)

Comment: Toby: the haagerup tp is only defined in the category of op spaces.

Comment: That's what I thought (although Matt mentioned the *extended* HTP and I'm unclear about the difference).  Possibly there is some natural way to equip a Banach space with a default operator-space structure, but then is Matt Daws's response to Dmitri's question even correct using the EHTP of the predual with its default op-sp structure? (instead of the op-sp structure that it gets from the algebra structure on its dual).

Comment: @TobyBartels, let me please hijack your question: is there any standard text laying down the basics of "coalgebras + functional analysis", i.e. C^*-coalgebras and related stuff? I have visited your nLab link, but there is no bibliography therein, so I wonder whether all this is your own view of the subject, or the general consensus on it? I.e. why are the concepts defined the way they are, why the projective tensor project and not any other one, why short maps etc.

Comment: @AlexM. :  That nLab page, which has been frozen for the past 11 years, should be updated; but in brief, the definition there is the correct one from a category-theorist's perspective if you think of Ban as a closed category (with the Banach space of bounded linear maps from V to W as [V,W]) and do everything automatically from there.  But the problem is that it doesn't have many examples, as shown by Yemon's answer, and there are other tensor products on Ban that, while not closed, have more interesting coalgebras.  So all that needs to go in there.

Comment: @AlexM. :  I forgot to tag you in my previous comment and I don't know if the edit will fix that.

Comment: @AlexM. :  Oh, I can tell you why only short maps though; that's the category that gets you the correct isomorphisms.  The hom-set (V,W) is the set of short linear maps, but the internal hom-object [V,W] is the Banach space of all bounded linear maps, so they're still there.  (You can think of the underlying set of a Banach space as the set of elements of its closed unit ball, not the set of all of its elements.)  It's a weird perspective, since it means that Ban isn't a concrete category in the usual way, but it works out.

Comment: @TobyBartels: I understand. So, unlike {Banach, C^*, W^*}-algebras (which are universally agreed-upon concepts), the "co-" analogues have not received a definitive shape yet?

Comment: @AlexM. :  If anything, they seem to work better with the injective tensor product on Ban.  This isn't closed, and it doesn't make sense (or at least doesn't work as well, I don't remember how badly) if you extend to nonarchimedean fields.  But it has more coalgebras.  Unfortunately, I haven't really thought about this stuff in a decade.

Comment: @YemonChoi may know more.

Answer (score 3):

Only a partial answer, but I thought I'd stick it up to give other people something to poke holes in or build on. Hopefully I will come back to elaborate or correct.

Let $M$ be the W*-algebra whose predual $A$ is your co-algebra. Then your comultiplication is meant to land in $A\hat{\otimes A}$, I gather. So dualizing you want your multiplication on $M$ to be a well-defined map $(M_*\hat{\otimes} M_*)^*\to M$. But now I *think* one can invoke machinery from tensor norms of Banach spaces to say that this would imply multiplication in $M$ extends to a well-defined continuous linear map $M\check{\otimes} M \to M$ where $\check{\otimes}$ is Grothendieck's injective tensor product. Then if you want this map to be contractive I believe $M$ has to be commutative. If you want it to be bounded, I think you even need $M$ to be a finite sum of (commutative) $\otimes$ (matrices).

Comment: I am coming to this 8 years too late... But Quigg's paper (https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=806641) shows _exactly_ this, in Section 5.  However, this only shows that the coproduct $\Delta$ on $A$ is _bounded_ iff $M$ is as stated.  The original question wanted this map to be "short", that is, contractive.  Surely then you only get commutative vn algs, but I don't quite see the proof.  Similarly, for a full answer, you then need to character which commutative vn algs give $\Delta$ mapping into $A\widehat\otimes A$, and not something larger.

Comment: @MatthewDaws 8 years is fine, I'm still one day going to solve the problems from my PhD...

Comment: @MatthewDaws to show contractive forces M to be commutative, maybe show things go wrong for 2 by 2 matrices, and then argue that a noncommutative M contains a copy of ${\bf M}_2$. But as you say it's not clear if M commutative is even sufficient to get $\Delta(A) \subseteq A \hat\otimes A$