# Criteria for $(V \otimes W)^* \cong V^* \otimes W^*$ in Banach spaces

Tags: banach-spaces, c-star-algebras

Let $V$ and $W$ be Banach spaces.

$V^* \otimes W^*$ embeds into $(V \otimes W)^*$ (projective tensor product). I am looking for criteria for it to be an isomorphism.

If $V$ and $W$ are $C^*$-algebras, is this an isomorphism?

If $V$ and $W$ are reflexive, is this an isomorphism?

This property is one which commonly is useful, especially when I want to take the dual of an algebra (which makes a coalgebra if this holds).

Thanks very much!

Comment: If your tensor denotes the projective tensor product then the map you have described below is usually not bounded below when both V and W are infinite dimensional. Much as one might like this property to hold it will fail if both V and W are infinite-dimensional Cstar algebras or infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces, and indeed probably for "most" infinite-dimensional Banach spaces.

Comment: Loosely speaking, the "dual" tensor norm to the projective tensor norm is the injective tensor norm. You can see this if you take $V=W=c_0$, and then $V^* \widehat{\otimes} W^*$ is (isometrically) isomorphic to $(V \otimes_\varepsilon W)^*$. You might find some of the discussion on this old MO question helpful: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105502/which-w-algebras-are-the-duals-of-c-coalgebras?rq=1

Comment: Thanks Yemon! If you write this as an answer, I will accept and upvote.

Comment: Returning to your question concerning reflexive spaces: The dual of $V\otimes_\varepsilon W$ is then $V^* \otimes _\pi W^*$ provided one of these spaces has Grothendieck's approximation property. (There's a more general such theorem involving spaces with the Radon-Nikodym property.)

Comment: Good point @DirkWerner - also Dean, you might want to keep in mind that in general $\ell_\infty({\bf N}) \otimes_\varepsilon \ell_\infty({\bf N})$ is a closed subspace of $\ell_\infty({\bf N}\times {\bf N})$ but it is much smaller, and so if one wants to do Hopf-von Neumann algebras one can't base it on these "small" tensor products, one needs some kind of "extended" or "weak" version

Comment: (Sorry for not getting round to writing a proper answer - been busy with "the day job")