# Examples of isomorphic W* algebra with non-homeomorphic weak topology

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, duality, preduals

Due to the uniqueness of the predual, a W* algebra, when realized as a von Neumann algebra in any way, always has a unique, well-defined ultraweak (or $\sigma$-weak) topology. The same can be said about the ultrastrong (or $\sigma$-strong) topology and ultrastrong-$\ast$ (or $\sigma$-strong-$\ast$) topology. In his book [*The Theory of Operator Algebras, vol I*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=dTnq4hjjtgMC&lpg=PP1&hl=fr&pg=PA136#v=onepage&q&f=false), in the remark after Corollary 3.11, Takesaki claims that

> ...the weak topology, the strong topology, and the strong$\ast$ topology on a $W^\ast$-algebra do not make sense unless we specify on which Hilbert space the algebra acts.

My question is a concrete instance of the more general question [Can we recover a Von Neumann algebra from its predual?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/50302/128540)(perhaps I should add that what Dmitri Pavlov called a von Neumann algebra in that question is what I call a $W^\ast$-algebra here, and for me, a von Neumann algebra is an involutive subalgebra of $\mathcal{B}(H)$ which coincides with its bicommutant, thus depends on the $C^\ast$ algebra $\mathcal{B}(H)$, and in particular on the Hilbert space $H$). More precisely, I ask to construct explicit examples illuminating the remark of Takesaki quoted above.

Since the weak (resp. strong, strong-$\ast$) topology coincides with the ultraweak (resp. ultrastrong, ultrastrong-$\ast$) toplogy on bounded parts, the construction of such an example is not trivial.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that the question is more trivial than I expected. We can just take an infinite dimensional von Neumann algebra $M$ acting on a Hilbert space $H$, then consider the diagonal map $\Delta: \mathcal{B}(H) \to \mathcal{B}(H^\infty)$, where $H^\infty$ is the direct sum of an infinite copies of $H$. Then obviously, the weak topology on $(M, H)$ is different from that of $(\Delta(M), H^\infty)$, since the dual space (the space of weakly continuous functionals) for the latter is strictly larger.